# What will be the sequence of SQL Join query execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When we have multiple  Join queries , Derived table join query and finally where conditions,  What will be the sequence of SQL Join query execution?

Which block of code will get executed first (or) whether outermost block or inner most block  of code in SQL ?

```
select 
  TablePerson.PersonName, TablePet.PetName, TablePet.PetType
from 
  TablePerson
left outer join 
(
  select TablePet.ownerID, TablePet.PetName, TableTypes.PetType
  from TablePet 
  inner join TableTypes on TablePet.PetTypeID = TableTypes.TypeID
) 
  TablePet
on
  TablePet.OwnerID = TablePerson.PersonID
```

Comment: your derived table will be executed first, or before it is joined at least. Regarding join's in your outer query, the order you write them does not matter (if you had more tables to join). You could check your execution plan... it always tells you how it was executed :D

Comment: In case if we dont have the derived table join query, and regular set of Inner Join or left join queries.. how the execution takes place.. , bottom to the top or top to the bottom ?

Comment: Which ever it chooses and it could be done in parallel. Also, what if you had a where clause? It makes sense this subset is usually evaluated first, before the joins.

Comment: *"In case if we dont have the derived table join query, and regular set of Inner Join or left join queries.. how the execution takes place.. , bottom to the top or top to the bottom ?"* in general most modern RDMS optimizers would look which table has the lesser records (when match) to be fetched first and join futher on...

Comment: Thank you .. what does most modern RDBMS optimizer .. , is it SQL 2017 or from 2012 onwards ??  What was the sequence execution for 2008 R2 version ??

Comment: With RDMS i mean Relational Database Management System in general meaning SQL Server (MSSQL), MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle database, SQLite.. The basics of handing join are more or less the same in anny RDMS, well some optimizers are better and have better algoritmes like join hashes... But like @scsimon suggested check the execution plan and you know more how SQL Server (MSSQL) handles queries.. Seeing a query and saying what a optimizer might do is very hard if not impossible without knowing table structures/data distribution also because optimizers are heavy beasts code wise and logical wise..

Comment: So for SQL Server it builds a query plan which ideally is the "best" or most optimal. However, this is VERY hard to get right, especially consistently... and then it'll cache that plan so it doesn't have to spend resources figuring this out next time it executes the same query. There's a lot of literature on why this is hard, but one of the best resources is a video with MIT professor and RDMS legend Dr. DeWitt. [Check it out here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQfJkNqmHB4)

Comment: its from brent ozar..  i read them all the time.. thanks for sharing :)

Comment: *"However, this is VERY hard to get right, especially consistently... and then it'll cache"* @scsimon the query plan cache only makes it harder, imagine if data grows that fast that cache plan really is out of date or non optimal annymore basically its like a extra step where things can get out of date but i do know you can manually clear that cache.. To tell you the truth iam more a MySQL guy then a SQL Server guy, just starting to learn SQL Server aswell.

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland that’s what I implied

Comment: @RaymondNijland how long to cache each plan is one of the hard problems for the query optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural language.  A SQL query represents the result set, not the specific actions to generate it.

SQL basically has three steps in processing a query:

- Parsing the query
- Optimizing the query to generate the best execution plan for the data
- Executing the query

*The exact same query can have different execution plans at different times, depending on the data and the environment.*

This is very important to understand.  You cannot specify what the execution plan is.  The optimizer determines that -- regardless of CTEs and subqueries.  You can influence the execution plan by providing hints in the query.

Comment: Thank you.. and so based on execution plan , we can further optimize the table..layout.. , One last question .. lets say in the ON condition for the JOIN Query .. one of the mapping column does not have any index.. i can add NON Cluster Index to it .. right?? Doing so will increase some performance .. ??

Comment: @goofyui Sometimes. No guarantees. If you don't create the right (covering) index, it may not be used at all. And if you write more often than you read, you have to consider if the cost of maintaining the index is worth the benefit.